# Nesting of JSONobjects from a JSONArray based on given keys

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert a JSONArray to "grouped" json object format.

There can be N number of columns represented by C1, C2, C3...

Here the data is grouped by the order - C1, C2, C3

Sample JSONArray

```
[
  {
    "C1": 1001,
    "C2": 2001,
    "C3": 3001,
    "count": 10
  },
  {
    "C1": 1001,
    "C2": 2001,
    "C3": 3001,
    "count": 8
  },
  {
    "C1": 1001,
    "C2": 2001,
    "C3": 3003,
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "C1": 1001,
    "C2": 2002,
    "C3": 3001,
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "C1": 1002,
    "C2": 2002,
    "C3": 3001,
    "count": 9
  },
  {
    "C1": 1002,
    "C2": 2002,
    "C3": 3002,
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "C1": 1003,
    "C2": 2001,
    "C3": 3001,
    "count": 2
  }
]
```

Expected output format

```
  "C1": [
    {
      "id": 1001,
      "C2": [
        {
          "id": 2001,
          "C3": [
            {
              "id": 3001,
              "count": 10
            },
            {
              "id": 3002,
              "count": 8
            },
            {
              "id": 3003,
              "count": 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2002,
          "C3": [
            {
              "id": 3001,
              "count": 5
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1002,
      "C2": [
        {
          "id": 2002,
          "C3": [
            {
              "id": 3001,
              "count": 9
            },
            {
              "id": 3002,
              "count": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1003,
      "C2": [
        {
          "id": 2001,
          "C3": [
            {
              "id": 3001,
              "count": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Points I considered before I began

- Only the inner most object will have the count
- I'd need a map to have references of the object that I encountered earlier
- For every object in the JSONArray, I'd have to loop through the available fields

Sample code I tried

```
    public static JSONObject process(JSONArray dataArray, List<Field> fieldList) {
        // To save the ID vs JSONArray to put later
        Map<String, JSONObject> idObjectMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        int numberOfFields = fieldList.size();
        JSONObject returnObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray finalArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject rowObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfFields; j++) {
                Field field = fieldList.get(j);
                // getColumnName() will return C1/C2/C3 ...
                String id = rowObject.get(field.getColumnName()).toString();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("id", id);


                // Only the inner most object will have the count
                if (j + 1 == numberOfFields) {
                    int count = rowObject.getInt("count");
                    jsonObject.put("count", count);

                }
                idObjectMap.put(id, jsonObject);

            }
        }
        
        return returnObject;
    }
```

Question:

I'm not sure how to proceed after this. I tried to switch the loops and process, but I seem to have difficulty in keep in the reference the objects that were formed earlier. I'm having trouble with nesting the objects too. If anyone could guide me or give some tips, it'd be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly solve this by constructing the result JSONObject on the fly, using existing nested objects or creating them in case they do not exist yet.

Note that this code has not been tested yet and its performance can probably be improved.

```java
public static JSONObject process(JSONArray dataArray, List<Field> fieldList) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject element = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject currentParent = result;

        for (Field field : fieldList) {
            String columnName = field.getColumnName();
            int id = element.getInt(columnName);

            JSONArray children = currentParent.optJSONArray(columnName);
            if (children == null) {
                children = new JSONArray();
                currentParent.put(columnName, children);
            }

            // Find the child with matching `id`
            JSONObject child = null;
            for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < children.length(); childIndex++) {
                child = children.getJSONObject(childIndex);
                if (child.getInt("id") == id) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // No matching child found, create new one
            if (child == null) {
                child = new JSONObject();
                child.put("id", id);
                children.put(child);
            }
            // Update parent
            currentParent = child;
        }

        // The most nested object should store the `count`
        currentParent.put("count", element.getInt("count"));
    }

    return result;
}
```